# Error in deleting a dynamic object?

Tags: c++, file, malloc, free

I am allocating a memory for union in heap and i need to delete the object of union when the element `Id` of union is 900.

Please help me to delete `groupUnion[i]` object when the `Id` is 900 
below is my code.

```
groupUnion = (SettingsUnion *) malloc(sizeof(SettingsUnion) * (NumAttrs + 1));
if(groupUnion == (SettingsUnion *) NULL)
{
    return (FALSE);
}

for (unsigned int i=0; i < NumAttrs; i++)
{
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&groupUnion[i]),sizeof(SettingsUnion));
    if(groupUnion[i].Id == 900)
    {
        free groupUnion[i]; // this is bad how can i delete groupUnion[i] when groupUnion[i].Id == 900
        groupUnion[i] = NULL;
    }
}

inFile.close()
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You cannot "unallocate" a piece of memory in the middle of an already allocated memory. However, I highly doubt it's what you want - if you deallocate a piece of memory, you cannot access it anymore, so you cannot know that it was `Id==900`. What you really want to do?

Comment: [This link explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) how you can do this.

Comment: Do not use malloc/free in C++. Use vector, unique_ptr, make_unique, new/delete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment `free groupUnion[i];groupUnion[i] = NULL` lets me assume that you actually want to express an array of *pointers to `SettingUnion`-objects* rather than an array of `SettingUnion`-objects. 
So your code could look like as follows (I used your `malloc`/`free`-style, though in C++ you actually would use `new`/`delete`):

```
groupUnion = (SettingsUnion **) malloc(sizeof(SettingsUnion*) * (NumAttrs + 1));
if(groupUnion == NULL)
{
    return (FALSE);
}

for (unsigned int i=0; i < NumAttrs; i++)
{
    groupUnion[i] = malloc(sizeof(SettingsUnion));
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&groupUnion[i]),sizeof(SettingsUnion));
    if(groupUnion[i]->Id == 900)
    {
        free groupUnion[i];
        groupUnion[i] = NULL;
    }
}
inFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot free part of the allocated memory: free groupUnion[i]

What you can do however is to allocate individually the elements and then free them individually:

```
// not sure why you need the +1 (anyway you allocate an array of pointers to the struct here. Consider using new operator)
groupUnion = (SettingsUnion **) malloc(sizeof(SettingsUnion *) * (NumAttrs + 1)); 
if(groupUnion == (SettingsUnion *) NULL)
{
    return (FALSE);
}

for (unsigned int i=0; i < NumAttrs; i++)
{
    // you allocate the individual groupUnion here:
    groupUnion[i] = (SettingsUnion *) malloc(sizeof(SettingsUnion));
    if(groupUnion[i] == (SettingsUnion *) NULL)
    {
        return (FALSE);
    }

    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&groupUnion[i]),sizeof(SettingsUnion));
   if(groupUnion[i].Id == 900)
   {
        free groupUnion[i]; // this is bad how can i delete groupUnion[i] when groupUnion[i].Id == 900
        groupUnion[i] = NULL;
   }
}

inFile.close()
```